# How to show Validation message in Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have tried showing an error message in a Controller and it doesn't work, but when I use `dd`, it works.

**My Code:**

```
if ($validation->fails())
{
    /*Doesn't work
    foreach ($validation->fails() as $messages) {
        $messages // Doesn't work
    }
    */
    dd($validation->errors); //This works
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I noticed none of the provided examples here actually work! So here you go. This was my found solution after realizing that `validator->messages()` returns a protected object which isn't retrievable.

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    foreach ($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages)
    {
        var_dump($messages); // messages are retrieved (publicly)
    }

}
```

I would reference [MessageBag](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html), which is what `messages()` returns. And for additional acknowledgement of the Validator class - reference [this](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html).

Answer (score 2):

`$validation->fails()` returns a boolean of whether or not the input passed validation. You can access the validation messages from `$validation->messages()` or pass them to the view where they will be bound to the `$errors` variable.

See the [validator docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#error-messages-and-views).

Comment: can you tell my how do that? i dont want to pass them into the view

Comment: In your controller you can loop through the validation messages as such: `foreach($validation->messages() as $message) { /**/ }`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have just used in an artisan 5.0 console command, to validate the arguments. This is in the `fire()` method:

```
    // Create the validator.
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $this->argument(),
        ['field1' => 'required|other|rules']
    );

    // Validate the arguments.
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        // Failed validation.

        // Each failed field will have one or more messages.
        foreach($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages) {
            // Go through each message for this field.
            foreach($messages AS $message) {
                $this->error($field_name . ': ' . $message);
            }
        }

        // Indicate the command has failed.
        return 1;
    }
```

This is an extension on the answer from @tfont

You may need to change where the message is sent (`$this->error()`) if this command is not being run as an console command, ie CLI, command-line.